# Give an Example of a Bijective Function $\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ with precisely $r$ orbits

Tags: group-theory, functions

This problem is a continuation of what was discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1595407/four-problems-concerning-orbits-of-biconditional-functions-f-a-rightarrow-a).

As the title states, I wish to find a bijective function $\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ with precisely $r$ orbits. I observe from the definition of an orbit $O_a$ that, essentially, each of its members depend on the preimage $a$. Hence, if the domain is infinitely large, in this case $\mathbb{Z}$ is $\aleph_0$ large, then there will be just as many orbits (again $f$ is bijective, so this seems to be a safe conclusion regardless of how $f$ is defined). For this reason, a bijective function $f: \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ with infinitely many orbits is simply the identity mapping.

Assuming my observations are correct, I cannot see how a bijective function with $\mathbb{Z}$ as its domain can have finitely many orbits, unless for an arbitrary $r \in \mathbb{N}$, we take a finite nonempty subset $V \subseteq \mathbb{Z}$ such that $|V| = r$ as the domain and codomain of the function $j: V \rightarrow V$ defined by $j(v) = v$ for all $v \in V$. It would then follow that the number of orbits depend on the cardinality of V, namely the arbitrary natural number $r$.

Any insight or assistance would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: An orbit is not necessarily finite.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I agree, but the quantity of orbits can be finite. Did I accidentally imply that an orbit can be finite?

Comment: Well. If you can partition $\Bbb Z$ into $r$ non-empty sets, then you can easily find a bijection as wanted. Unless you had the misconception that orbits have to be finite, I'm not sure where the difficulty lies.

Comment: (Not to mention that "a bijective function" has no business concerning being a group homomorphism, or any structural preserving properties. It might, but you don't have to be married to that idea. I'm saying that because you tagged this as "group theory".)

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood how the number of orbits is determined, which is in my post. If I am wrong, what determines the quantity of orbits?

Comment: You can visualize an orbit as follows. Draw a directed arrow from $x$ to $f(x)$. Two points are in the same orbit if they can be connected by a sequence of arrows.

Comment: To answer the question in your latest comment, one way to determine the quantity of orbits is to find a "set of representatives", which by definition is a subset $R \subset \mathbb{Z}$ such that $R$ contains exacty one element of each orbit. It follows that the number of orbits equals the cardinality of the set $R$. In the answer of @AndreNicolas, the set $R=\{1,2,…,r\}$ is a set of representatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Map any integer $z$ to $z+r$. The congruence classes modulo $r$ are the orbits.

**Remark:** In the OP, the comment was made that the only bijective function with infinitely many orbits is the identity function. There are many more. For example, we can use the function $f$ that for all $z\in \mathbb{Z}$ interchanges $2z$ and $2z+1$.